# Japanese unicode in string

Tags: c#, string, unicode

How do i store a Japanese character in a string without the extra slash?

```
string jap ="\\x30F8";
```

prints "\x30F8" while

```
string jap = "\\\x30F8";
```

prints "\ヸ"

Comment: sorry about it was just a testing international characters and name the variables with the the first 3 letters of the country.

Comment: @RaymondChen taking offense at a normal abbreviation of a country name in code, where abbreviating variable names is more than normal, is kind of taking political correctness too far.

Comment: @Niels That particular abbreviation happens to be a racial slur. The recommended abbreviations are `jp` and `jpn`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Keep in mind that this is an international site. You cannot expect people from 200+ countries, many of which barely speak English well enough to post a question, to then understand all the intricacies and deeper feelings behind any possible word and who might be offended by it. Political correctness is for political boards, not an international programmer's forum. I'm not a native English speaker myself and didn't realize someone could be offended by `string jap;` either until you pointed it out.

Comment: Somehow my original comment was deleted, but I merely pointed out that the OP in the future should choose a different abbreviation, understanding that he most likely was not aware of its taboo nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one backslash is necessary in a hexadecimal escape sequence:

```
string text = "\x30F8";
```

You can also use a Unicode escape sequence:

```
string text = "\u30F8";
```